# Sharing Objects b/w tests in Testng

Tags: unit-testing, testng

In Junit only static objects can be reused b/w tests, but in Testng objects can be reused without declaring them static. Is there some way to turn off this feature of Testng?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Probably the fact that TestNG doesn't reinstantiate test classes in-between method calls. If you are seeing something wrong, all you need to do is move the initialization of the field in a `BeforeMethod`.